# Вопрос по Python и Selenium, почему переходит только по первой ссылке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Фрагмент кода:

```py
def parse_url(self, element):
    href_list = []
    url = element.find_element_by_css_selector('a.bloko-link.HH-LinkModifier')
    href = url.get_attribute('href')
    href_list.append(href)
    for i in href_list:
        self.parse_element(url = i)

def parse_element(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)
    company_name = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.bloko-gap.bloko-gap_bottom')
    print(company_name)
```

Во второй функции на первой строке делает запрос только по первой ссылке, и выдает только один результат.

В первой функции точно не одна ссылка в `href_list`.

Ведь на каждой итерации `webdriver` должен осуществлять запрос.

Comment: Эм. В `parse_url` в *пустой* `href_list` добавляется только один элемент. Вот и получается что итерация только одна

Answer (score 2):

Как заметил [icYFTL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/280323/icyftl) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1147859/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be-python-%d0%b8-selenium-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b5#comment1987976_1147859), в функции `parse_url` в переменную `href_list` добавляется всего один URL-адрес. Если подразумевается, что блоков с селектором `'a.bloko-link.HH-LinkModifier'` несколько, то для получения их всех необходимо использовать метод `find_elements_by_css_selector` аргумента `element`, который возвращает объекты на все блоки с подходящим селектором. Обратите внимание, что в названии метода используется множественное число "element**s**", в отличии от метода, использованного вами.

Так же, для извлечения значения блока нужно использовать свойство `text` элемента.

В этом случае код будет выглядеть как-то вот так:

```py
def parse_url(self, element):
    urls = element.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.bloko-link.HH-LinkModifier')
    href_list = [u.get_attribute('href') for u in urls]
    for i in href_list:
        self.parse_element(url = i)

def parse_element(self, url):
    self.driver.get(url)
    company_div = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.bloko-gap.bloko-gap_bottom')
    company_name = company_div.text
    print(company_name)
```